# Second quantization of schrodinger field

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Schrodinger field is quantized by expanding the wave function in terms of some complete orthonormal set of eigen function. Then quantization is done by specifying the suitable relations between annihilation and creation operators depending whether we want to use this formalism for boson systems or fermion systems. 
   Using bosonic commutation rules between annihilation and creation operators. I tried to reduce the discussion of BE statistics to the study of the group SO (2,1) and vice-versa but I could not get the desired result. Help me.

Comment: " I tried to reduce the discussion of BE statistics to the study of the group SO (2,1) and vice-versa but I could not get the desired result." This single sentence contains most of the actual content of your question. Could you expand upon it a bit and describe exactly what you did and what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: I wanna know how the analysis of group S0(2,1) leads to BE statistics